# Can't reach by link Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am new with Spring framework and right now I'm trying to learn few things but facing a problem. (Learning from this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). So by default, I can launch my program via 
`localhost../greeting`, but what if I want to change the name not like in the website with `/greeting?name=xx`, but for example `/greeting/Tom..` (`/greeting/{name}`)

Comment: Hi!
Do you mean you want sent name like /greeting/{name} instead of /greeting?name=Tom?

Comment: Yeah. I don't want to use this sentence ?name=.... As I mentioned I want to use /greeting/Tom for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In GreetingController:**

Instead of this:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name)
```

Implement this:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting/{name}") 
public Greeting greeting(@PathVariable("name") String name)
```

for optional path variable:

```
@PathVariable Optional<String > name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in you example defaultValue does not work anymore, so I can't launch program without greeting/name

Comment: Hehe, found it before you posted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you need here is called PathVariable.
  This article is very useful to understand all the difference between types of requesting

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-QueryParam-and-pathParam-in-Webservices

Comment: This one was useful. Thank you